# functions and events in OCI

Tags: oracle-cloud-infrastructure, oracle-cloud-functions

I have a scenario in where I want to run commands in instance using functions based on events in OCI(oracle cloud infrastructure).
flow :
object storage: object update/modification -> trigger event -> execute function : to run commands in specific instances using `run command`
Is this achievable ?
As currently I see that to execute `run command` service we would need oci config files(profile)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this, you can use the OCI Java or Python SDK within the function to invoke the Run Command API.

See API details at “[Using the API](https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/Content/Compute/Tasks/runningcommands.htm)” in the docs. You will also need to configure the Functions resource principal to have access to the Compute instance in question. See [this](https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/Content/Functions/Tasks/functionsaccessingociresources.htm) for details on configuring the Functions resource principal