# Oracle Cloud - Trigger Compute Instance Run Command based on Condition

Tags: oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I want to be able to `run command` on multiple instances based on a trigger when uploading or changing a file in a bucket.
However, I'm not able to find how to do this in the Oracle API reference, see [API Reference - ComputeInstanceAgentClient](https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/tools/python/2.85.0/api/compute_instance_agent/client/oci.compute_instance_agent.ComputeInstanceAgentClient.html#oci.compute_instance_agent.ComputeInstanceAgentClient).
I struggle to find where to start and would appreciate any kind of help of this. I have however found a similar StackOverflow question, see below.

Ref:

- [functions and events in OCI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70648435/functions-and-events-in-oci)
- [OCI Docs - Running commands](https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/Content/Compute/Tasks/runningcommands.htm)

Comment: Have a look at the samples [here](https://github.com/oracle-samples/oracle-functions-samples), they should be a good starting point

Comment: THanks @gsalem. However I can not find a way to trigger the `run command` plugin.